# Filter DataTable on the base of a column having specific text

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

```
    public void giveusersforsearch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDal ob = new myDal();
        DataTable obj = new DataTable();

        obj = ob.givesearchtable();

        "Insertion of code"
    }
```

I am getting a table from a database and i want to filter the table according to a column name (name).

Comment: explain more on what you want to filter. It's really not clear

Comment: i want to search a substring in that colum (name) of that table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> res =  filteredDtobj.AsEnumerable().Where (dr=> ((string)dr["columnName"]).Contains("Something"));
```

This will emit the desired filtered rows.

Or you can use this :

```
DataTable res = filteredDtobj.Select("columnNamelike  '%Something%'").CopyToDataTable;
```

Comment: Royi, looks like OP wants to find a substring in column `name` but yeah your answer should get him to right way...

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is good but i will recomend to do this at the database lever like store procedure

Build and execute the select sats dynamic instead .
Like this execute "select * from table order by " + column 
Search google on execute SQL dynamic .

Comment: That should go as comment rather than answer. in memory search would be way better than making multiple calls to DB.

Comment: Yes but you would have the full acess to the data.  IF you have 10000 row is it a good exable to get all of them.  Think about.  Im trying to teach him the right way of doing this